# find square root with Newton using integers

Tags: c, numerical-methods, newtons-method, square-root

In this program, I'm trying to calculate the square root with the [newton equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) 1/2(x+a/x) just using integers. So if I repeat this equation at least 10 times, it should divide the number by 1000 and give an approximate value of the square root of a/1000. This is the code:

```
int main (){
    int32_t a, x;  //integers a and x
    float root;

     do{
    scanf ("%d", &a);   // get value of a from the user
    
    
    if (a < 1000 ){   // if chosen number is less than 1000 the programm ends.
    break;
    }
    
    x = ((float) a / 1000);   //starting value of x is a / 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50;i++)
    {

        root = ((float) x * (float) x + a/1000) / ((float)2*x);  // convert int to float //through casting
        x = (float)root;    // refresh the value of x to be the root of the last value.


    }
    printf ("%f\n", (float)root);
     }while (1);

    return 0;

}
```

so if I calculate the square root of 2000, it should give back the square root of 2(1.414..), but it just gives an approximate value: 1.50000
How can I correct this using integers and casting them with float?
thanks

Comment: `int32_t a, x;` can you instead define `a` and `x` as floats -> `float a, x;`, and `scanf ("%f", &a);`? should provide expected your expected value

Comment: `a/1000` (integer divsion) is certinaly amiss.  I'd expect `(float) a / 1000`.  Angie, did you want integer division in `((float) x * (float) x + a/1000)`?

Comment: Could it be that you missed completely the intent of the task? As per the title, there should be no floating point numbers at all in the computation. As I see it, for the integer input `a` you have to do the Newton/Heron/Babylonian method in integer arithmetic for `1000*1000*a` to get an integer result close to `1000*sqrt(a)`, thus getting about 3 digits after the dot for `sqrt(a)`.

Comment: As said by @LutzLehmann, your approach is not "just using integers".

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main (int argc, char * *argv, char * *envp) {
        int32_t a, x;  //integers a and x
        float root;
    
        do {
            scanf ("%d", &a);   // get value of a from the user
            if (a < 1000) {   // if chosen number is less than 1000 the program ends.
                break;
            }
            x = (int32_t)((float) a / 1000.0f);   //starting value of x is a / 1000;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
// Fixed formula based on (x+a/x)/2
                root = ((float)x + (((float)a) / (float)x)) / 2.0f;
//Below, wrong old formula
                //root = ((float) x * (float) x + a / 1000) / ((float) 2 * x);  // convert int to float //through casting
                x = (int32_t) root;    // refresh the value of x to be the root of the last value.
            }
            printf ("%f\n", root);
        } while (1);
    
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you can explain what was wrong in the original code, and how the changes you made in your version fix the problem.

Comment: @G.Sliepen The formula says that: (x+a/x)/2 But he wrote it wrongly. I fixed the formula. – 
LORDTEK
32 secs ago

Comment: Great! You should edit your answer and point that out. I would just show line with the error before and after the fix.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I put comments based on your comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't divide the number the user enters by 1000. So if I enter the number 2000 it should print out the value of the root square of 2 and not 2000. Anyways, thanks.